# Trouble Connecting Local Server to MongoDB Despite Configuring Network Access

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am currently working on a project where I need to connect to a MongoDB instance from two different servers: one is a Heroku server and the other is my local development server.

I have successfully set up my Heroku server to connect and interact with MongoDB without any issues. However, I am having trouble establishing a similar connection from my local server.

I am unsure why this is happening as I'm not manually terminating the process and there doesn't seem to be any unhandled exceptions causing the process to crash.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any insights on what could be causing this disconnection? Any help in troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

The code:

// db.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const dbURI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

mongoose.connect(dbURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB connection established!");
});

mongoose.connection.on("error", (error) => {
  console.error(`MongoDB connection error: ${error}`);
  process.exit(-1);
});

//New Unhandled exceptions method
mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`MongoDB connection disconnected: ${error}`);
    process.exit(-1);
  } else {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(0);
  }
});

// Handle SIGINT event for graceful shutdown
process.on("SIGINT", (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  connection.close(() => {
    console.log("MongoDB connection closed due to app termination");
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

// // server.js

```
`// Load the required packages
const express = require("express");
const nodemon = require("nodemon");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors");

// Load the environment variables from the .env file
dotenv.config();

// Initial database connection
const db = require("./data/db");

// Import routes
const linkButtonRoute = require("./routes/linkButtonRoute");

// Create an express app
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Use the express.json() middleware to parse incoming request bodies
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());

// Set the port for the application
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Mount the routes to the express app
app.use("/api/linkButton", linkButtonRoute);


// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
`
```

To ensure that the MongoDB instance can be accessed from any IP, I have configured the network access settings in MongoDB Atlas to "0.0.0.0/0". Despite this, I am still unable to maintain a connection from my local server to MongoDB. The connection gets established initially but disconnects shortly after, and I'm not sure why this is happening.

Here is the log:

//New Unhandled exceptions method

```
mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`MongoDB connection disconnected: ${error}`);
    process.exit(-1);
  } else {
    console.log(
      "MongoDB connection disconnected through app termination " + error
    );
    process.exit(0);
  }
});
```

The logs:

```
C:\Users\Lior\AppBar-Server\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:825
  const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
                               ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT 15.185.70.41:27017
    at Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Lior\AppBar-Server\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:825:32)
    at C:\Users\Lior\AppBar-Server\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:419:10
    at C:\Users\Lior\AppBar-Server\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Lior\AppBar-Server\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Lior\AppBar-Server\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1272:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Lior\AppBar-Server\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:418:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lior\AppBar-Server\node-js-getting-started\data\db.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-02.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-02.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 183346427,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 15.185.70.41:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\Lior\AppBar-Server\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:387:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lior\AppBar-Server\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:310:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 15.185.70.41:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
            errno: -4039,
            code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '15.185.70.41',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      },
      'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-00.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-00.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'RSSecondary',
        hosts: [
          'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-00.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017',
          'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-01.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017',
          'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-02.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017'
        ],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {
          region: 'ME_SOUTH_1',
          nodeType: 'ELECTABLE',
          provider: 'AWS',
          workloadType: 'OPERATIONAL'
        },
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 17,
        roundTripTime: 321.9200000000001,
        lastUpdateTime: 183346522,
        lastWriteDate: 2023-05-23T13:11:54.000Z,
        error: null,
        topologyVersion: {
          processId: ObjectId { [Symbol(id)]: [Buffer [Uint8Array]] },
          counter: 11
        },
        setName: 'atlas-yyc43k-shard-0',
        setVersion: 2,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
        primary: 'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-02.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017',
        me: 'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-00.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017',
        '$clusterTime': {
          clusterTime: Timestamp { low: 2, high: 1684847514, unsigned: true },
          signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
        }
      },
      'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-01.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-01.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'RSSecondary',
        hosts: [
          'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-00.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017',
          'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-01.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017',
          'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-02.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017'
        ],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {
          provider: 'AWS',
          workloadType: 'OPERATIONAL',
          region: 'ME_SOUTH_1',
          nodeType: 'ELECTABLE'
        },
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 17,
        roundTripTime: 322.56000000000006,
        lastUpdateTime: 183346518,
        lastWriteDate: 2023-05-23T13:11:54.000Z,
        error: null,
        topologyVersion: {
          processId: ObjectId { [Symbol(id)]: [Buffer [Uint8Array]] },
          counter: 11
        },
        setName: 'atlas-yyc43k-shard-0',
        setVersion: 2,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
        primary: 'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-02.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017',
        me: 'ac-0qzaeb7-shard-00-01.nxgkbuq.mongodb.net:27017',
        '$clusterTime': {
          clusterTime: Timestamp { low: 2, high: 1684847514, unsigned: true },
          signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
        }
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-yyc43k-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30
  },
  code: undefined
}

Node.js v18.12.0
```

Comment: which OS you are using??

Comment: @TanishqChawda Windows

Comment: When it disconnects, what is the log you are getting?

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC The server falls on a "disconnected" event and the error is undefined, I don't know why.

Comment: Can you share your logs please?? @liorlsa9

Comment: @TanishqChawda share the image or just the prints?

Comment: @TanishqChawda the logs appear at the bottom of the question.

Comment: just share the logs image and also logs

Comment: @TanishqChawda
OK, I comment out the code after this block:
mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB connection established!");
});

So I can see the logs.
The logs appear at the bottom of the post.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/getting-etimeout-error-when-attempting-to-connect/180683/7 this might help you @liorlsa9 please look into it